# Swift 3 parsing youtube videos doesn't show results and keeps loading - IOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10

I'm trying to fetch youtube channels and videos by json parsing, and I'm new to Swift 3. However, the loading icon doesn't disappear, and no result are shown, With no errors in the log.

this is my code :

1/ func getVideosForChannelAtIndex :

```
func getVideosForChannelAtIndex(_ index: Int!) {

    let playlistID = channelsDataArray[index]["playlistID"] as! String
    let urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=\(playlistID)&key=\(apiKey)"
    let targetURL = URL(string: urlString)
    var url = URLRequest(url: targetURL!)
    url.httpMethod = "GET"
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse

        if httpStatus!.statusCode == 200 && error != nil {



            do {
                let resultsDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

                let items: Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> = resultsDict["items"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>

                for i in 0 ..< items.count {
                    let playlistSnippetDict = (items[i] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["snippet"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

                    var desiredPlaylistItemDataDict = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()

                    desiredPlaylistItemDataDict["title"] = playlistSnippetDict["title"]
                    desiredPlaylistItemDataDict["thumbnail"] = ((playlistSnippetDict["thumbnails"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["default"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["url"]
                    desiredPlaylistItemDataDict["videoID"] = (playlistSnippetDict["resourceId"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["videoId"]

                    self.videosArray.append(desiredPlaylistItemDataDict)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Error while loading channel videos: \(error)")
        }

        self.activityView.isHidden = true
    }



        }
```

2/ func getChannelDetails :

```
func getChannelDetails(_ useChannelIDParam: Bool) {

    var urlString: String!

    if !useChannelIDParam {
        urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails,snippet&forUsername=\(desiredChannelsArray[channelIndex])&key=\(apiKey)"
    }
    else {
        urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails,snippet&id=\(desiredChannelsArray[channelIndex])&key=\(apiKey)"
    }

    let targetURL = URL(string: urlString)
    var request = URLRequest(url: targetURL!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse

        if httpStatus!.statusCode == 200 && error != nil {



            do {
                let resultsDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

                let items: AnyObject! = resultsDict["items"] as AnyObject!
                let firstItemDict = (items as! Array<AnyObject>)[0] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

                let snippetDict = firstItemDict["snippet"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

                var desiredValuesDict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
                desiredValuesDict["title"] = snippetDict["title"]
                desiredValuesDict["description"] = snippetDict["description"]
                desiredValuesDict["thumbnail"] = ((snippetDict["thumbnails"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["default"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["url"]

                desiredValuesDict["playlistID"] = ((firstItemDict["contentDetails"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["relatedPlaylists"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["uploads"]


                self.channelsDataArray.append(desiredValuesDict)


                self.tableView.reloadData()

                self.channelIndex += 1
                if self.channelIndex < self.desiredChannelsArray.count {
                    self.getChannelDetails(useChannelIDParam)
                }
                else {
                    self.activityView.isHidden = true
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        } else {
            print("Error while loading channel details: \(error)")
        }
    }



    }


    }
```

3/ func textFieldShouldReturn:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    activityView.isHidden = false

    var type = "channel"
    if segmentDisplay.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

    type = "video"
        videosArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

    }
    var urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=\(textField.text)&type=\(type)&key=\(apiKey)"

    urlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!



    let targetURL = URL(string: urlString)

    var request = URLRequest(url: targetURL!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse
if httpStatus!.statusCode == 200 && error != nil {


    do {
        let resultsDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

        let items: Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> = resultsDict["items"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>

        for i in 0 ..< items.count {
            let snippetDict = items[i]["snippet"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

            if self.segmentDisplay.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                self.desiredChannelsArray.append(snippetDict["channelId"] as! String)
            }
            else {
                var videoDetailsDict = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
                videoDetailsDict["title"] = snippetDict["title"]
                videoDetailsDict["thumbnail"] = ((snippetDict["thumbnails"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["default"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["url"]
                videoDetailsDict["videoID"] = (items[i]["id"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["videoId"]

                self.videosArray.append(videoDetailsDict)

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    if self.segmentDisplay.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        self.getChannelDetails(true)
    }

}
else {
    print("Error while loading channel videos: \(error)")
}

self.activityView.isHidden = true
    }


    return true


}
```

Comment: Where do you call resume() ? You need to add .resume() to the dataTask closing curly brackets

Comment: That's a lot of code, at least you should fix the indent before posting them.

Comment: I updated the code by adding the other methods, but can't find where I should insert the .resume() that you have indicated. My apologies if the code and/or the question seem to bother, but I'm new to both IOS and Stackoverflow. Thanks Leo ;) .

Comment: Will do Yuchen :) I'm having a problem with indents but will fix it. I'm new to Stackoverflow, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you have to call `resume()` on each task, because all tasks of `URLSession` are suspended by default.

Using your one-liner this way:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

  ...

}.resume()
```

Alternatively

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

  ...

}
task.resume()
```

By the way the `URLRequest`instances are not needed at all. `GET` is the default HTTP method.

Note: Make sure that all optional values embedded in the URLs with string interpolation are unwrapped otherwise you'll get literal `Optional("Foo")` strings. For example `textField.text` in the third code snippet is definitely an optional.

Comment: Thank you Vadian :) Can you explain the purpose of .resume

Comment: Used it but the fetched data is returned as nil (null), i don't know what seems to be the problem.

Comment: I doubt if this is correct, but is this the way to unwrap the optional textField.text : 




`/* fetch an optional */
let textField.text = fetchOptionalString()`




`/* now unwrap it */
if let unwrapped = textField.text {
    print(unwrapped)
}`

Comment: Yes, optional binding (`if let`) is the recommended way to safely unwrap optionals.

Comment: Still doesn't work, I'm really confused as to what may be the reason of no results returning, I made sure it is not a 403 authorization error, other than that i'm baffled.

Comment: Print the composed URL and paste it in a browser. Does it work?